# Filter multiple sheets based on dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with the following dropdown

- All teams
- Team A
- Team B
- Team C

Based on this dropdown I want to filter the rest of the tabs starting from tab 9. So, if you set the dropdown to Team A you will only see the data of Team A in the data from tab 9 on. I managed to do this with the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        For i = 9 To Worksheets.Count
            Worksheets(i).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The dropdown is located in cell C2, the sheets I want to filter start in tab 9.

My issue: when "All Teams" is selected in the dropdown, how do I make sure that all data shows up and not just the team specific data? It should be something like "If C2 = "All Teams" Then no filter" but no idea how to put this in VBA...

Best,

Comment: Try `If C2 = "All Teams" then Worksheets(i).ShowAllData else ...`.

Comment: Hey Axuary, thanks a lot. How would you add it to the current macro? Still pretty new to VBA...

Comment: It goes in the for loop right before `Worksheets(i) ...`,  Essentially what it would do is if C2 is "All Teams" then it clears the filter, otherwise it filters on the value in C2.

Comment: Currently I have it like this:

```Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        For i = 9 To Worksheets.Count
    If C2 = "All" Then
        Worksheets(i).ShowAllData
    Else
        Worksheets(i).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Does not seem to work... (used "All" as this is what I am actually using in the sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like this.

```
Dim i As Integer
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        For i = 9 To Worksheets.Count
            If Range("C2") = "All" Then
                Worksheets(i).ShowAllData
            Else
                Worksheets(i).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
            End If 
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! This did the trick! Have a nice day :)

Comment: I came across an issue with the macro. Once the data is filtered and I want to select some rows, the selection is not visible on your screen  (I can see a correct avg., count, min, max, sum). Any idea how to solve this?